# How to add dependencies in two custom iOS framework?

Tags: frameworks, dependencies, cocoapods, git-submodules, ios-frameworks

I have created custom frameworks to use in my current iOS app.

- profileManager.Framework
- messagemanager.Framework
- requestManager.Framework

Now both profileManager.Framework & messagemanager.Framework are actually using requestManager.Framework methods so what I want is that in my Xcode project of app I only want to keep only one physical copy of the requestManager.Framework code.I want that my request manager code should have only one copy per app and the reference should be linked with other framework.

We have created this frameworks on local machine & now my problem is we can't add dependencies in  profileManager.Framework or either in messagemanager.Framework. I want to know that how it can be possible that my both framework will use network manager from app with a single copy of its in application.

Answer (score 1):

Have that framework at your single view application level and make sure the framework path is given correct in build settings of App and as well as Framework.

This way you maintains only one copy of framework that too at Project level and feel free to use in Project or Project Framework level.

Comment: can you please elaborate it more.

Comment: Put the Network framework at your app level. For example put it in your project root directory and give that path in the build setting of your dependent framework(user and inbox) and app.

Answer (score 1):

How about trying to manage the dependencies of those frameworks with CocoaPods?
In the podspec of `UserManager.Framework` and `InboxManager.Framework` , configure the dependencey like `s.dependency 'NetworkManager', '~> 1.0'`. In this way, you can have only one physical copy of the NetworkManager.framework code in your app.

For example, `AlamofireImage` and `Alamofire-SwiftyJSON` both have the dependency on `Alamofire` but only one physical copy of the `Alamofire.framework` installed in the app with running `pod install`.

Reference: [AlamofireImage.podspec](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage/blob/master/AlamofireImage.podspec), [Alamofire-SwiftyJSON.podspec](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON/blob/master/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON.podspec)

Comment: I know that solution but we don't want to put framework at GitHub. We have tried to give s.dependency with local path. but its not working

Comment: Have you already tried [Private Spec Repo](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html)?